# MySQL Error: Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out and wonder if anyone here could give me a helping hand. In short, the trigger and all of that works just fine in the table as long as I don't write the manual query. If I delete a record

Query:

```sql
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `lastonline` < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `CLEANUP` AFTER DELETE ON `users`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM account_data WHERE account_data.owner = old.identifier;
        DELETE FROM inventory_items WHERE inventory_items.owner = old.identifier;
        DELETE FROM datastore WHERE datastore.owner = old.identifier;
        DELETE FROM invest WHERE invest.identifier = old.identifier;
        DELETE FROM user_stats WHERE user_stats.identifier = old.identifier;
    END
END
```

Comment: It seems you are using a trigger for cleaning up the data, which could be done via cascaded deletes in foreign keys.

Comment: i can't reproduce it, can you provide a fiddle